# ReferenceError: setCookie is not defined

Tags: jquery, setcookie

I get this error on button click. Here is the code

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$(document).on('click','#frontpanel_basicthreedot', function frontcookie(){

    setCookie("frontdata" , "frontpanel_basicthreedot" , 24);

    })
});
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you never defined a function named `setCookie`, nor does any such function exist as global...

Answer (score 3):

You are missing a function:

```
function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
    var d = new Date();
    d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "expires="+ d.toUTCString();
    document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
}
```

If you want to do this using jQuery, you can use https://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/

Using `$.cookie()` function, you can set / get cookie value very easily

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','#frontpanel_basicthreedot', function frontcookie(){
        $.cookie("frontdata" , "frontpanel_basicthreedot" , { expires: 1/*day*/ });
    })
});
```

Here are some set cookie example :

```
//To set a cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value');


//Create expiring cookie, 7 days from then:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7 });


//Create expiring cookie, valid across entire page:
$.cookie('the_cookie', 'the_value', { expires: 7, path: '/' });


//Read cookie
$.cookie('the_cookie'); // => 'the_value'
$.cookie('not_existing'); // => null


//Delete cookie by passing null as value:
$.cookie('the_cookie', null);

// Creating cookie with all availabl options
$.cookie('myCookie2', 'myValue2', { expires: 7, path: '/', domain: 'example.com', secure: true, raw: true });
```